# Regex in PHP to match words with some excepetions

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

```
$matchstring  = 'MS-DOS file';
$string1 = 'MS-DOS file';
$string2 = 'MS-DOS file, NE Windows';
$string3 = 'MS-DOS file, MZ OS-windows';
$string4 = 'MS-DOS file, Clear OS-windows';
```

I am writing the regex to march the string 'MS-DOS file' in above strings to only match `$string1` and `$string4`. The pattern should not match the 'MS-DOS file' which is followed by the keywords 'NE' or 'MZ'. For other it should match like it should match string 4 but not string 2,3

Any ideas ?

I was tried this with my poor regex but no luck :(

```
if (preg_match("/MS-DOS file[\s]?[^MZ][^NE]/", $string1)){
    echo "True";
} else{
    echo "False";
}
```

Comment: If they are always exact these strings, why not reproduce them exact? So with `$string1|$string2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
"/MS-DOS file(?:,\s|$)(?!MZ|NE).*/"
```

You were overlooking the comma and misusing the character set square brackets.

EDIT: Also, I believe you want to check for 'NE', not 'NI'.

Comment: @Asad Regex is good it just make ',' compulsorily because it works for string4 but not for string1 because it dont have ',' in it

Comment: @Shashi Edited as per your request.